# Can't call a function defined in external JS file

Tags: javascript, function

Wanted to try out using external JS file, but I can't seem to be able to call a function I defined there. Every time I try to call it, an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: calculate (function name) is not defined" is returned. I've been coding for only a week, so trying to figure out my error myself led me nowhere.

Chunks of code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset= "utf-8">
    <script type= "text/javascript" src= "nameOfFile.js"></script>
</head
```

Trying to call the function:

```
<select type= "select" id = "currency" onchange= "calculate()">
                        <option value= "RUB", selected> RUB </option>
                        <option value= "USD"> USD </option>
                        <option value= "EUR"> EUR </option>
                        <option value= "GBP"> GBP </option>
```

The function in external file:

```
function calculate() {
 var currencyName = document.getElementById("currency");
 var currency = currencyName.value;
 var time = document.getElementById("timeInput");
 var sum = document.getElementById("sumInput");
 var amount = sum.value;
 var income; //pure percent revenue
 var earnings; //income + revenue
 var result = document.getElementById("results");
 var percentage;


 switch (currency) {
    case RUB:
        if (time>= 3 && time <= 5) {
            percentage = 5;
        }
        else if (time >= 6 && time <= 11){
            percentage = 6;
        }
        else if (time >= 12 && time <= 24){
            percentage = 6,5;
        }

     break;

    case USD:
        if (time>= 3 && time <= 5) {
            percentage = 0,1;
        }
        else if (time >= 6 && time <= 11){
            percentage = 0,5;
        }
        else if (time >= 12 && time <= 24){
            percentage = 1;
        }
    break;

    case EUR:
    case GBP:
        if (time>= 3 && time <= 5) {
            percentage = 0,1;
        }
        else if (time >= 6 && time <= 11){
            percentage = 0,25;
        }
        else if (time >= 12 && time <= 24){
            percentage = 0,5;
        }
    break;
 }

 income = percentage / 100 * amount;
 earnings = amount + income;
```

}

The page seems to recognize the existence of .js file, I can see it in "Sources" tab in Chrome, for example. Both files are in the same folder.

EDIT: Problem solved, see my answer.

Comment: Can you add the whole `.js` file?

Comment: is that the full js file or is there more? is the function declaration nested in somthing?

Comment: html and js both file on same folder?

Comment: Try using `javascript:change()`

Comment: @WasteD Kinda embarrassing, but added the whole function in the question for ya

Comment: @GhanshyamBaravaliya yes, they are

Comment: why do you think that the function doesn't run? because you don't see anything change? Well, the function doesn't change anything, it doesn't log or alert anything, it just computes some values and throws them away when the function exits. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: try using  `OnChange="Javascript:return calculate();"`

Comment: @Thomas He said he gets an "Uncaught ReferenceError: calculate (function name) is not defined"

Comment: and `percentage = 6,5` doesn't mean what you expect *(although it is valid JS)*. Numbers in JS use dots: `percentage = 6.5`

Comment: @Thomas wow, didn't notice that, thanks.

Comment: @GhanshyamBaravaliya doesn't seem to work, nothing has changed.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number
5tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_inaccurate2:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined  --- Same issue here when I put var x=5,2, please change that percentage=6.5. Hope it will work

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, problem was that I accidentally added some HTML code in the external JS file.

I noticed that I had paragraphs at the bottom (for some reason...) and when I deleted them and fixed commas to dots (thanks, Tristup and Thomas), everything started to work fine.

Comment: it does? because you have a few more mistakes in there: `value= "RUB", selected` here should be no `,`, these: `case RUB:` should be strings `case "RUB":` and should throw errors at the moment, your `</head` tag is not properly closed, and I don't know wether you just missed to copy the closing `</select>`-tag, or wether it is missing in your markup.

Comment: Yeah, i noticed all this mess, while searching for problem , fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

Can you load the script at the bottom or in Footer section of the HTML. May be the function unable to recognize the element that are called into it.

To check that file is included properly. You can write alert("hi"); at the top of the file that included.

Please let me know if you need to know anything more on it.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Please use try this  case 'USD':

Comment: Please check your console for the error, which does not let your function to load. Please fix "percentage = 6,5;" should be "percentage = 6.5;" . Comma "," is not allowed here in javascript for precision.

Comment: `percentage = 6,5` is perfectly valid JS. But you're right, it does not do what he probably intended/meant.

Comment: Thomas,

Just tried to see in w3c,                                                            <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Floating point arithmetic is not always 100% accurate.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = 5,2;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>

Comment: Seems that not working, you may be talking about the percentage function where the number of precision is specified in this way.

Comment: no, I'm just saying that this ain't a syntax-error. *It's valid syntax!* maybe this makes it a little more clear what the comma-operator does here: `var x = alert("hi"),1,2,3,4; alert("x = " + x);`

Comment: sry, my bad, made a mistake in the snippet: the `var` there changes the meaning of that, and makes this invalid. It has to be `var x;` and then `x = alert("hi"),1,2,3,4,alert("x = " + x);`